# Is removing permissions going to cause the extension being disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I used to have the v1 of the extension in the store with a set of permissions, when I published v2, I added two more permissions:

1. A "content_scripts" field with a "matches" entry that matches all
   hosts using https://*/*
2. A "nativeMessaging" permission

These changes in v2 caused the extension being disabled and showed the following warning messages to users when they got the update:

To re-enable it, accept the new permissions:

- Read and change all your data on the websites you visit
- Communicate with cooperating native applications

The warning message have caused lots of the users to remove the extension, so I am considering to publish a new version v3 to remove the two newly added permissions. In v3 it has the same set of permissions with v1.

My question is what will happen to users after I publish v3:

1. For users who is still in v1 (haven't got the v2 update), will they still get the extension being disabled first?
2. For users who have already accept v2's permission, will removing permissions cause the extension being disabled again?
3. For users who is still having the v2 extension disabled (they didn't accept and didn't remove it), will publish v3 help enable the extension directly?

Comment: I think you can test it all yourself using an unpublished extension in your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

> For users who is still in v1 (haven't got the v2 update), will they still get the extension being disabled first?

No, this happened to me once and the extension was not disabled.

> For users who is still having the v2 extension disabled (they didn't accept and didn't remove it), will publish v3 help enable the extension directly?

No, the user will need to both accept the permissions for v2 and explicitly enable the extension.